# python 2d packing irregular shapes one by one

Tags: python, image, packing

**the context:**

an artpiece where i iteratively fit irregular blobs into a square and paint the outcome with my drawing robot.

**the problem:**

I have a bunch of irregular shapes that

- can resize between a maxsize and a minsize
- can rotate
- are irregular in shape

and i need to place them, **one by one**, in a rectangular so i minimize the empty space.

Special problem constraints:

1. i need to place them, **one by one**, and do the computation only for the next item, i cannot use packing algos that know the next items, in plural, since that information does not exist.

.

**My question:**

1. What is the name of this problem ?
2. Can you give some directions on how to approach this, relevant papers etc?

my question is related to 
[Packing An Irregular Polygon with Different Sized Circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860687/packing-an-irregular-polygon-with-different-sized-circles)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. If you end up doing something concrete and running into trouble, we'd be glad to help out though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry i am not experienced in writing questions here. 
To clarify:
am not looking for a solution, i am just lost without any direction to seek information that EVENTUALLY will make me solve my issue :-)